# How to use xpath to extract the price of a stock from google finance?

Tags: php, xpath

I can't seem to get my xpath query to find it.

```
$pathTemplate =  "https://www.google.com/finance?q=";

echo "Enter the stock symbol of the stock you want to check\n";
$foo = fgets(STDIN);

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html -> loadHTML($pathTemplate . $foo);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$price = $xpath -> query("//span[@class = 'pr']/span/text()");
echo $price -> item(0);
```

[I got a screenshot of the developer tools window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHBGY.png)

Comment: You need to use the id 'price-panel'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should normalize (always) classes when using xpath to be able to handle a `class="class1 class2"` tag properly.

the best way to get what you want is by targeting the `ID="price-panel"` first.

below a complete working snippet, you forgot to `file_get_contents` so you were trying to parse the URL as HTML instead of the actual HTML ;-)

```
$pathTemplate =  "https://www.google.com/finance?q=";

echo "Enter the stock symbol of the stock you want to check\n";
$foo = fgets(STDIN);

$html = file_get_contents($pathTemplate . $foo);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom -> loadHTML($html);


$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$price = $xpath -> query(" //div[@id='price-panel']//span[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' pr ')]/span");
$price = $price->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $price;
```

Comment: How did you decide that targeting the price-panel was the best choice of action?

Comment: you look for something that is as unique as possible and will most likely not change to much. IDs are unique and this one is explicit enough that you can assume it will stay the same.